# "Nicht unerheblich" vs. "erheblich" - is there a difference?

Tags: word-usage, adjective, meaning-in-context

We can see that both, *"erheblich"*, and *"nicht unerheblich"* are used in the meaning of e.g. *"considerable, extensive, remarkable"*.

> Branchengerüchten zufolge können die Besucherzahlen dank des Knopfes um bis zu das Sechsfache steigen. Und selbst große Seiten profitieren davon **nicht unerheblich**.<sup>[Die Zeit](http://www.zeit.de/digital/datenschutz/2011-03/facebook-like-datenschutz)</sup>
>
> Seit dem Wochenende ist bekannt, dass Landesbehörden für die Überwachung digitaler Kommunikation zwischen Verdächtigen höchst umstrittene Software verwenden: Sie kann **erheblich** in die Grundrechte der Betroffenen eingreifen, ohne dass dies rechtlich gedeckt ist.<sup>[Die Zeit](http://www.zeit.de/politik/deutschland/2011-10/datenschutz-trojaner-datenschutzbeauftragte)</sup>

Is there a different nuance in meaning? When do we use one or the other?

Comment: M.E. muss es - Zeit hin oder her - `um bis auf das Sechsfache steigen` oder `um bis um das Sechsfache steigen`, aber nicht `um bis zu das Sechsfache` - `um bis zu dem Sechsfachen` oder `um bis zum Sechsfachen` wäre wieder in Ordnung.

Comment: No, it's not related. But I don't like to see bad language uncommented here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A phrase of the type "nicht unerheblich" is called a [Litotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litotes). It is a rhetorical figure.

Both phrases mean the same. It is also true for both, "erheblich" and "nicht unerheblich", that the degree to which the statement being made applies varies with how it is made. Much depends on prosody and facial expression.

Be aware that using "nicht unerheblich" might introduce structural ambiguity:

> Sie kann [nicht unerheblich] in die Grundrechte der Betroffenen eingreifen.
>
> Sie [kann nicht] [unerheblich in die Grundrechte der Betroffenen eingreifen].

Answer (score 2):

We use the same rhetorical device in English: you can say:

> It is not impossible for man to fly.

rather than

> It is possible for man to fly.

They have the same meaning, but the former is "denying the negation," rather than supporting the original claim directly.